# Table color between date

Tags: php, magento

I want a table with colors based on a date. If the date (sold product) is 20 - 12 - 2013 than color is green till 7 days after. After 8 days tabel color must be red.

```
$current_time = $col->getCreatedAt();
    if ($current_time) {
    $style = "green";
}
if ($current_time >+ 8) {
    $style = "red";
}
```

Comment: `>+` should be `>=` shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `>+` to `>=` . Also have a look [Comparison Operators](http://php.net/ternary) in php

```
if ($current_time >= 8) {
$style = "red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a simple comparing error. Try this:

```
if ($current_time >= 8) {
    $style = "red";
}
```